# Uploading a switch appliance on GNS3

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, kvm, gns3

I recently installed GNS3 on Ubuntu, using KVM-qemu as the virtual machine. I installed the GNS3 on a remote server hoping to work on topologies with my friends. The installation was successful but I am having issues uploading a switch appliance to the server.

I can access the GNS3 VM (server) through its web interface
[gns3 web interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEfWw.png)

**How I uploaded the appliances.**

I downloaded Aruba .ova image, extracted it to get .vmdk file, then I converted it to .qcow2

then I uploaded it via
edit/preference/'Qemu VM'/'add VM appliances'
[qemu appliance uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuLs3.png)

when I powered it on this screen (below) will display then a blank page with a blinking prompt.
[the first page when the appliance is powered on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NAHg.png)

if I follow this method https://docs.gns3.com/docs/using-gns3/beginners/import-gns3-appliance/
I will end up with this when booting up the device.
[error on bootup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJfD4.png)

Note:
i am using virt-manager to manage the VM
[virt manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JioPj.png)

I am expecting to be able to upload and use any .qcow2 device appliances on the server and access it from my laptop. Not just me but my friends as well.

Any one of us can build topology, save it and it can be accessed by all.

I will be happy if someone who have done this could help me out.
I am open to other ways of achieving this same result.